# How to hide text in screen capture and then save it to gallery

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a feature for which I need to make sure that if a user tries to take a screen capture, some of the data displayed will be hidden in the screenshot. Is it possible to implement it?

While doing research I found [BasicScreenCaptureProcessor](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/runner/screenshot/BasicScreenCaptureProcessor), but I am not sure if I am on the right track

Comment: hi and welcome to SO! Please consider adding more details of what have you done, and what is exactly the problem with using `BasicScreenCaptureProcessor`?